# Is System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt needed to work with JWT when using IdentityServer's IdentityModel library?

Tags: jwt, identityserver4

I have a simple command-line client for an existing web-service that uses IdentityServer4. The client receives a JWT back from IdentityServer4 that contains the user's claims which are used by the client.

I noticed that the IdentityServer's `IdentityModel.dll` library does not include any functionality for parsing JWT tokens to extract the claims. I saw some examples ([like this one](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/src/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L148)) use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which is defined in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` - which itself has dependencies on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`, and `Newtonsoft.Json`.

That's a lot of dependencies for just extracting encoded text from a JWT.

I'm not asking for a library recommendation, just confirmation that it is best-practice to use `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to extract claims from a JWT when using `IdentityModel.dll`.

Comment: like this one link is now dead, I could really use the context reference to figure out what appears to be the same problem

Comment: @Maslow I have updated the broken link. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

IdentityModel.OidcClient.IdentityTokenValidator uses JwtSecurityTokenHandler internally when validating the token, so yes, that's a normal way.
Alternatively you can, yes, use a helper method `Base64Url.Decode(b64url)` from Identity and then Newtonsoft.Json to parse a raw token.

 Nevertheless, much more convenient approach exists to list **user** claims when using complete OidcClient such as [the one from IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2):

```
var result = await oidcClient.LoginAsync();
cfg.accessToken = result.AccessToken;
cfg.identityToken = result.IdentityToken;
cfg.refreshToken = result.RefreshToken;

if (result.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nError:\n{0}", result.Error);
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("\n\nClaims:");
foreach (var claim in result.User.Claims)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", claim.Type, claim.Value);
}
```

(see the complete example [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/NetCoreConsoleClient/src/NetCoreConsoleClient/Program.cs))

Comment: I see the `IdentityModel.OidcClient` NuGet package - how does that compare to the client inside `IdentityModel.dll` exactly? Don't they both do OAuth2 + OpenID Connect?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/ is a dependency for https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel.OidcClient/. The first one provides some base stuff such as constants, contracts, http clients for different endpoint types etc. The last one is a complete OIdC client implementation. You can combine, for instance, just Identity for simpler discovery etc with some basic stuff from MS, or you can employ some extended features of IdSrv, such as reference tokens, in combination with IdentityModel.OidcClient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it properly (i.e. with signature validation etc) then yes, that's the usual way in .Net-land.

If you want to extract info from the token but don't care about trusting it then you just need to be able to decode base64url strings and parse JSON but I'd not recommend this.